# Stream can not be read (StreamReader .net), send from Internet Explorer 10 with angular (1.5) $http.post and json as data

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, internet-explorer-10

Call:

```
$http.post(serviceName, data, { tracker: tracker });
```

Content-Type is application/json;charset=utf-8 says ie10

Read:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(rawJSON);
```

Length of Stream is `0`, which is not when send by other browsers (chrome..).

[rawJSON content exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/378Ts.png)

[image: Profiled request type, headers,..]

[image: Profiled data body]

Comment: What you get inside rawJSON?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the data is being successfully sent from the browser? Enable the network profiler in IE10's dev tools and confirm that it's sending the data you expect.

Comment: it really looks ok outgoing - I attached two more pictures of ie10 dev tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the serviceName string did not end with a slash

```
"path/service"
```

Internet Explorer 10 and 11 could not interpret this slash adequately. After inserting a slash:

```
"path/service/"
```

ie10, ie11 understood the request like expected.